# Parse Geo location ISO 6709 into double array

Tags: php, regex, geolocation

How to parse Geolocation  ISO 6709 in the format  `±DD.DDDD±DDD.DDDD` using php into double[lat,long]?

examples:

`'+18.81983-19.91984'` would be `Array ( [0] => +18.81983 [1] => -19.91984 ) )`

`'-8.8194+29.81982'` would be  `Array ( [0] => -8.8194 [1] => +29.81982 ) )`

`'+29.1989+54.01983'` would be  `Array ( [0] => +29.1989 [1] => +54.01983) )`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want? do you want the double[] be be something like this `double[0] = +18.81983` and `double[1] = -19.91984`?

Comment: updated to reflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
preg_match_all('/(\+|\-)(\d+\.?\d+)/', '+18.81983-19.91984', $matches);
echo  $matches[0];
```

Let me know how that works for you.